# Comments With Leading Space

Tags: bug, comments, design

I just saw this comment on an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47368560/4333555):

[image: Screenshot]

The spacing seems strange to me. If you post a comment below this comment as well the indentation drops to one space.

The poster said they added one space to start the comment.

Comment: This has also been posted on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359286/6083675), with more details.

Comment: @Laurel Ah, didn't search on the SO meta forum. I usually assume these bugs are SE wide.